# Android NavUtils not firing getSupportParentActivityIntent api 15

Tags: android

Using the support version of NavUtils (import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils), in api 16+ overriding the getParentActivityIntent() method fires correctly when calling NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent().  However in api 15 and under, neither the support nor standard method is triggered:

```
public void onUp() {
    Intent parentIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
    ...
}

@Override
public Intent getParentActivityIntent() {
    //fires in api 16+
    return super.getParentActivityIntent();
}

@Override
public Intent getSupportParentActivityIntent() {
    // never fires
    return super.getSupportParentActivityIntent();
}
```

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSupportParentActivityIntent()` get called from [onSupportNavigateUp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#onSupportNavigateUp()), which by default is called whenever the Up button is pressed in your `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` as seen [in the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java#146). It automatically creates the `TaskStackBuilder` for you, calling the other support methods as needed as seen in the [onSupportNavigateUp() source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java#336).

If you're not using the standard `ActionBar` or a `Toolbar` with `setSupportActionBar()`, you can call `onSupportNavigateUp()` directly.

Comment: So `NavUtils.navigateUpTo(activity, upIntent);`is not expected to work if the parent activity is not declared in the manifest?

Comment: @mdelolmo - I'm not sure what you mean. The `upIntent` is what is created from the manifest entry - if you're supplying your own `upIntent` then the manifest entry isn't involved at all.

Comment: Let me elaborate:
If my activity does not declare a `PARENT_ACTIVITY` `<meta-data>` element in the manifest in any way but overrides `getParentActivityIntent()` and `getSupportParentActivityIntent()` to provide the parent activity intent. Will `NavUtils.navigateUpTo(activity, upIntent);` return the parent intent?
As per the [documentation]  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html), not necessarily.  
I was just curious, because I ended up using `onSupportNavigateUp()` directly.

Comment: @mdelolmo - calling `NavUtils.navigateUpTo()` requires passing in an `Intent`. It does not search for an Intent either by looking in your manifest or calling any method. `onSupportNavigateUp()` has the advantage of also calling `supportShouldUpRecreateTask()` which is needed if your Activity supports deep linking. Hence, why my recommendation in my answer was to use `onSupportNavigateUp()` (assuming you do not use the default `ActionBar` or `setSupportActionBar()` as those will call it automatically).

Comment: Oops! Silly me! I was meaning `getParentActivityIntent(Activity sourceActivity)` the whole time... Naturally `NavUtils.navigateUpTo(activity, upIntent);` takes an Intent